# where is the bitcoin's private key saved?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, private-key

I'm making a service and I will have to take charge of users' private keys
So I'm really worried about it.how should i take charge of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not ask users for their private keys. Instead, generate new addresses (with private keys) for the users to deposit bitcoin into. Then ensure you keep those keys safe and secure, back them up and keep them encrypted

Comment: And then I shouldn't save the private key on databases?

Comment: You can use a bitcoin library or node to manage the keys for you, you only need the private keys when trying to spend the coins, not receive them

Comment: Yeah but I need to send their account so I need privacy key.i use bitcoind

Comment: You can interact with bitcoind's RPC interface to create new addresses and it will manage the private keys for you. By the way, if you are happy with my answer, please accept it :)